# Jquery plugin re-initialization after ajax

Tags: jquery, plugins

Hi I am using  uploadify and after the images are uploaded I wish to re-initialize the options so that the queuelimit is set to the remaining number of images.

The question is is there a way of reinitializing the options of a plugin that is set up on document.ready only once.
E.g

```
$().ready(function(){
  var options ={count:5}
  $("div").someplugin(options);
});
```

the count will change after the ajax call and the new count should be used.
Have tried to use a function for count like `{count:function(){}}` does not work.
Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$('#yourUploadifyElement').uploadifySettings('queueSizeLimit', yourNewLimit );
```

The docs say it only works for:

```
buttonImg, buttonText, cancelImg, fileDesc, fileExt, width, height, folder, script, scriptData, simUploadLimit, sizeLimit, hideButton
```

But I see nothing in the code prohibiting it working for queueSizeLimit.